# How to get data from database to textbox on VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net

hi im new in Visual basic. I have a button that when its clicked, its gonna find the student via their ID inputted by the user and its gonna output the data to the textfields. I'm not pretty sure if im doing this right. because i'm getting this error [image] >> http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/7650/gq0z.png

btw here's my code so far. can someone help me please? thanks!

```
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Student where Student_id = '" & id.Text & "'"
        cmd.Connection = db

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Try
            dr.Read()
            id.Text = dr.GetValue(0)
            Lname.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
            Fname.Text = dr.GetValue(2)
            Mname.Text = dr.GetValue(3)
            datet.Text = dr.GetValue(4)
            age.Text = dr.GetValue(5)
            male.Text = dr.GetValue(6)
            female.Text = dr.GetValue(7)
            status.Text = dr.GetValue(8)
            staddress.Text = dr.GetValue(9)
            cityAdd.Text = dr.GetValue(10)
            dr.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("" + ex.Message)
            dr.Close()
        End Try
```

Comment: if `id.Text` is empty you will get an error; you will also want to convert the **text** it contains to a number before you build the SQL.  In the future post the actual error message (they are important info) rather than a link to a picture

Comment: I would recommend a : `If NOT isdbnull(dr.getvalue(0))`... for each one obviously incrementing the getvalue number for each one.

Comment: Unsolicited Advice: go ahead and change `dr.getvalue(n)` to `dr.getvalue("nameOfColumn")`. Its a better habit.

Comment: thanks! gonna check on that.

Comment: or change that to `dr.item("nameofcolumn")` a bit shorter... see answer below

Comment: thanks guys! it's all working now! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Student where Student_id = '" & id.Text & "'"
```

change to:

```
if IsNumeric(id.text) Then
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from student where Student_id=@p1"
cmd.Prepare
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", id.text)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
....
Else
Exit Sub
End If
```

You can do it this way, or

```
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Try
       with dr
        .Read()
        id.Text = .GetValue(0)
        end with
        dr.Close()
```

or

```
with dr
    .read
    id.text = .item("id")
    .close
```

easier to read....

Answer (score 1):

First add a reference, if you are using MySQL database 
put it bet. the class

```
Dim Connection As MySqlConnection
Dim command As MySqlCommand
```

Put this to your textbox

```
Connection = New MySqlConnection
Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;port=3306;userid=root;password=root;database=databasename"
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
```

the root is default

```
Try
  Connection.Open()
  Dim query As String
  query= "Select * from Databasename.tablename where fieldname='" & textbox1.text & "'"
  Command = New MySqlCommand(query, Connection)
  reader = Command.ExecuteReader
  While reader.Read
    Dim sname As String
    sname = reader.GetString("Fieldname")
    textbox1.Items.Add(sname)
  End While
  Connection.Close()
Catch e MySqlException
  MsgBox (ex.Message)
Finally
  Connection.Dispose
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql Database, first add reference. To add reference of **MySql Database**

1. Go to your solution explorer and rightclick on your project name
2. Find add->references

   a window will be opened
3. In that window,under Assemblies select framework.
4. On right side there will be a list find and select Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatability.Data
5. In extensions, find and add MySql.Data and MSDATASRC
6. Click OK