# How To Fill Textbox With Datase Using Filter Button

Tags: vb.net

[Program ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUihk.png)

Hi I am creating a program and would like to ask for help.

I would like to fill the data on the four textboxes shown when I press the "ADD" Button (the input would be coming from the dataset), but first, the user must input a value on the other textbox at the top (the Item Code to be exact), basically to filter it first.

Would like to know the code on/or how to do it. TIA

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to post questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a search button. Once clicked, execute a query for the Item Code in DB to fetch the related record.
2. If record exist, Show Update button. Show the data in the textboxes. For this bind the textboxes with the datasource (i.e. DBSet used to fetch record from DB).
3. If record does not exist, Show Add button. Once data is entered into the textboxes, construct an insert query with the textboxes data and execute the insert query in DB.
4. Show the update or insert success/failure message to user.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I actually just need the first one but I'll take note of the others.  I'll try to update if I'm able to do it. Thanks

Comment: @S-E-RYS, refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642521/how-to-get-data-from-database-to-textbox-on-vb-net. You can also refer http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/find-specific-record-from-database-table-in-vb.net